# Não consigo criar uma nova Activity

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou fazendo um projeto que utiliza o jar v4 de suporte. Entretanto, quando eu crio uma nova Activity, o projeto fica com erros, pois ele informa que é necessário o support v7. Há possibilidade de continuar desenvolvendo este projeto utilizando somente o v4, ou ele foi descontinuado e agora só é possível utilizando o v7?

Aqui está meu *Android_Manifest*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.exemploactionbar"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".NoticeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_notice" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TesteActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_teste" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Tente utilizar a v7.appCompact ao invés da v7 padrão.

Comment: Consegui corrigir criando um novo projeto, e exportando as classes do proj anterior.

Answer (score 1):

Se você estiver incluindo o apoio `v4 e bibliotecas AppCompat v7` em seu aplicativo, você deve especificar uma versão mínima `SDK de 7` (e não `4`).

O nível mais alto da biblioteca de suporte que você incluir na sua aplicação determina o menor versão da API em que ele pode operar.

[Fonte](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/tools/support-library/setup.html)